# Tools to convert lisp code to assembly language

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, lisp, common-lisp, native-code

I have a lisp function. Is it possible to convert it to assembly language?

```
(defun isprime (num &optional (d (- num 1))) 
  (if (/= num 1) (or (= d 1)
      (and (/= (rem num d) 0)
           (is-prime  num (- d 1)))) ()))
```

The above code I want to convert it to assembly language. I am not sure if linux or windows have any tools to do it?

Comment: It's called a "compiler."  https://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/commonlisp.shtml

Comment: See the [`COMPILE`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_compile.html) and [`COMPILE-FILE`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_compile-file.html#compile-file) standard functions.

Comment: `(compile 'isprime)`

Comment: Note that you don't normally need to do this explicitly. Most Common Lisp implementations automatically compile functions when you define them.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to do that?

If you want to *study* how [Lisp compilation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cmp.htm) works, just use
[`disassemble`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_disass.htm):

```
(disassemble 'isprime)
```

If you want to *compile* the code for future use, then use [`compile-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm).

Answer (score 2):

"Is it possible to convert it to assembly language?"

Not as it currently stands. It has both `isprime` and `is-prime`. Correcting the second one to `isprime`, I can compile and run the `isprime` function. I also added a 'main' function, which does this:

```
(defun main ()
   (format t "Prime test on 23 is ~A" (isprime 23)))
```

I saved the whole thing in TestCompile.lisp

I am using Portacle / Windows to run SBCL / SLIME. I can compile a function by left clicking to put the cursor in the function, and then using C-c C-c. I can compile the whole file using C-c C-k, creating a FASL file.

From the REPL, I can now run `(main)`

```
CL-USER> (main)
Prime test on 23 is T
NIL
```

Finally, I decide that I want to create an executable. From PowerShell in the folder that contains the LISP source code:

```
sbcl
(load "TestCompile.lisp")
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die "prime.exe" :toplevel #'main :executable t)

./prime.exe
```

The executable is not compressed on Windows, and includes the compiler. It can be compressed manually using zip or similar.